# Thread access to global variable and force kill of old thread

Tags: java, multithreading

Everything is inside GUIActions class which has given fields:

```
public class GUIActions {
private GUIActions GUI;
private JButton connectButton;
private JTextArea messageArea;

private String IP;
private Integer PORT;
private CommunicationManager comManager;

public static Boolean flag = false;
```

I have code that deals with managing connection:
It initiate comManager and changes flag to true so ThreadManager will know that it has to start new ReceiverThread

```
class connectButtonActionListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        try {
            comManager = null; //to make sure that old connection is erased
            comManager = new CommunicationManager(IP, PORT);
            flag = true;
            if(!comManager.isAlive()) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Can't connect with server \n Server is either unreachable or offline");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Can't connect with server \n Server is either unreachable or offline");
        }
    }
}
```

Thread code:

```
/*
 * @desc Static method that setup GUI including adding tabbed cards into Frame
 * @param -none-
 * @return -none-
 */
public void setupGUI() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Chat Client");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    GUI = new GUIActions();
    GUI.setupCards(frame.getContentPane());

    Thread threadManager = new Thread(new ThreadManager());
    threadManager.start();

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

class ThreadManager implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Looking for connection!");
            if(flag == true) {
                System.out.println("Connection found!");
                Thread receiverThread = new Thread(new MessageReceiverRunnable());
                receiverThread.start();
                flag = false;
            }
        }
    }
}

class MessageReceiverRunnable implements Runnable {
    public synchronized void run() {
        System.out.println("Thread running");
        BufferedReader reader;
        String message;
        try {
            if(GUI.comManager==null) {
                System.out.println("comManager null");
                if(GUI.IP == null || GUI.PORT == null) {
                    System.out.println("IP or PORT null");
                }
                comManager = new CommunicationManager(GUI.IP, GUI.PORT);
                reader = comManager.getReader();
            } else {
                System.out.println("comManager NOT null");
                reader = GUI.comManager.getReader();
            }
            while((message = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                GUI.messageArea.append(message + "\n");
            }
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

So ThreadManager awaits for connection (comManager) and if there's connection it starts new Thread that will await for incoming messages.
I have two questions:

1)Why do I have to access GUIActions fields with GUI.IP or GUI.comManager instead of IP or comManager?

Runnable thread class is inside GUIActions class! Is it connected with that every thread has separate stack?

2)How can I force kill old receiverThread when there's new initialized?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have cannot access class member variables without using the object which conatains them. Its a rule in most languages, as they are not global constanst, the JVM (in this case) doesn't know to which variables you are refering to.

Could you clarify the question "Runnable thread class is inside GUIActions class! Is it connected with that every thread has separate stack?" ?

2. To kill the old receiver thread, store the MessageReceiverRunnable object in a variable and add a flag that would exit the run() method. When a new receiver thread is created, modify the flag so the thread finishes. Another option is to call interrupt() method on the thread.

Comment: It's like that: public class GUIActions { class MessageReceiverRunnable implements Runnable { //I can access only to GUI.IP and IP is null  } }

Comment: Because you are accessing the GUIAction object "GUI" that you have declared inside the class. To access the real IP and comManager you should use GUIAction.this.IP and GUIAction.this.comManager